# SFTP trigger stopped triggering

Tags: azure-logic-apps

One of my Logic Apps is triggerd by the SFTP trigger. Today I changed the watch folder to a different folder, and I can't get it to trigger any more. I had the issue previously and had to create a new SFTP connector. This time I was able to resolve it by creating a new Logic App with all the same logic as the original. This is simply not acceptable. Its as if when programming if your program stops working your only recourse is to write it from scratch. How is one supposed to diagnose a trigger not triggering? I don't want to be faced with trowing away all my work again in the future.

Comment: What is the interval you specified on the SFTP trigger to check for new items? Do you see new entry in the "trigger history" portion of the Logic Apps history?

Comment: Default of 2 minutes. The "trigger history" always shows "skipped".

Comment: Oh, and half an hour after my original post, the Logic App woke up and started triggering. This is VERY frustrating. Unreliable tech is not tech worth using.

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the path using design view or code view?

When using the *Code View*, You need to make sure you are also updating the **folderId** and the **metadata** properties.

**folderId** is a Base64 encoding of the path. The same for the first property the metadata object.[image]

When using the *designer view*, it seems that the **trigger state** (required to be able to recognise new items) is better refreshed when browsing through the folders on the SFTP trigger box (as opposed to just changing the path string) 
[image]

HTH

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've switched to always use the "browser" to change values. But that doesn't explain why it went quiescent for several hours.

Comment: Microsoft needs to add a better coding experience to Logic Apps - because whe're coders. This pointy-clicky stuff sucks here (as it does anywhere). PowerQuery did a much better job with the "M expression language" in terms of switching between code and UI. I do wish there was more cross-fertilization within MSFT.